# True or False: Let U= rowspace(A), V= columnspace(A), and W equal the vector space of all solutions to AX=0

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
        A= \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 2 \\
        -1 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 4 \\
        2 & 2 & 6 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

1. V=W
2. W⊆$R^3$

3)The rows of A form a basis for U

Why are these false? I can't find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

I think 2) is true: if $x$ satisfies $Ax=0$, it implicitly implies $x \in R^3$ (else you cannot multiply $A$ and $x$).

Consequently, $V \ne W$ since $V \subseteq R^4$ ($V$ is the span of columns of $A$, which are in $R^4$).

To show 3 is false, show that you can write one row as a linear combination of the others.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very hard to follow:

What examples do you want?

For the 1st part;

$AX=0\implies X=0$ .So $W=\ker A=\{x\in \Bbb R^3:Ax=0\}$ has dimension $0$ whereas $U=\text{Row Space of A}$ definitely has dimension $\ge 1$.

So $U\neq W$.Obviously $W\subset \Bbb R^3$.